# How to add new transform style to element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, transformation

When setting CSS3 transform property attributes are in a list. I have initially set translate x,y values for a set of images and once their dropped into a zone, I want to double the size (scale(2,2)). I can't cant seem to get both working. One thing I've tried is retrieving the translate values and reassigning the property. 
I was able to get the entire transform matrix (matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, -468, -959)) using

```
var width = window.getComputedStyle(event.relatedTarget,null).getPropertyValue('transform');
console.log(width);
```

which returned the values of matrix(scaleX(),skewY(),skewX(),scaleY(),translateX(),translateY()) to the console but I'm not sure how to parse it for the translateX and translateY values.

I was wondering whether might be a way to just append 'scale(2,2)' to the transform property. I can set just fine with:

```
event.relatedTarget.style.transform = scale(2,2);
```

but it just overwrites the translation which I want to preserve. Please let me know if anyone has any advice - much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply **contcatenate** the current **matrix** with the **new  transforms**:

```
currentTransformMatrix +" scale(2.2) rotate(20deg)"
```

Exaple:

```js
function addTransform(el, transforms){
  var matrix = window.getComputedStyle(el, null).transform;
  el.style.transform = matrix +" "+ transforms;
}


var box = document.getElementById("box");
addTransform(box, "rotate(20deg) scale(2.2)");
```

```css
#box{
  background:red;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  transform: translateX(100px);
  /* At a later time we want to add transforms rotation and scale
     but without losing the current translateX */
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```